# How to expand C drive in window 2003

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk-space

My C drive is 18GB.
I have other 18GB unpartined space on same HD.

I know that in vista i have the option to expand the disk by going in diskmanagement .
How can i do in window 2003

Answer (score 3):

**[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)** is your friend.

The GParted application enables you to change the partition organization on a disk device while preserving the contents of the partitions.

With GParted you can accomplish the following tasks:

```
* Create a partition table on a disk device.
* Enable and disable partition flags such as boot and hidden.
* Perform actions with partitions such as:
      o create or delete
      o resize or move
      o check
      o label
      o copy and paste
```

Comment: +1 because "GPartED is your friend" is EXACTLY what went through my mind, word for word. :)

Comment: Having a Linux Live CD, such as SystemRescueCD http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page and various other alternatives that are out there, is a must. It will allow you to do all kinds of system maintenance both when you can and can't get into Windows. If you don't have one of these discs I suggest you spend the time to download it and burn it right now. You will be glad you did in the future. GParted is included on the one I linked to.

Answer (score 3):

[Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) will be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In some rare cases using GParted on the system disk results in undesirable side-effects.

From [Extend a Windows Server 2003 disk volume](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5728477.html):

> Another option is to take advantage of
>   the new Diskpart.exe utility that
>   comes standard with Windows Server
>   2003. This utility allows you to create, delete, and manage partitions
>   on your hard drive.
>
> To use Diskpart.exe, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt by going to Start | Run.
> 2. Enter diskpart in the Open text box, and press [Enter].
> 3. At the DISKPART prompt, enter list volume.
> 4. Enter select volume x, where x is the volume number listed that you want
>      to expand.
> 5. Enter extend, and press [Enter].
>
> When you're finished, use the Disk
>   Management snap-in to check out your
>   new volume. It should now take up the
>   rest of the available space on the
>   device.

Do I need to mention backups, before such an operation.

Comment: Expending C: on the fly?

Comment: Yes, on the fly.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Diskpart does not allow you to extend the main partition on which you have installed windows.

Comment: @Mugen: You may try to move the page file to another partition, but this may or may not help. This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590) only says that *sometimes* the system cannot be extended. In that case, you will need a 3rd-party product.